# Getting parent object info from Flutter app

Tags: dart, flutter

I’m creating mobile application with Flutter.
This application has two forms (screens).
For example:

```
class MainScreen  extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AdvertAppBar(context),
      body: Container(…),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And

```
class ListScreen  extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AdvertAppBar(context),
      body: Container(…),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you could see I’m using shared appBar which instantiates from external class (`AdvertAppBar`).
Is there any way to know from appBar class what the class of parent object (`MainScreen` or `ListScreen`)?

Comment: You may be able to do this using the [inheritedWidgetOfExactType](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/inheritFromWidgetOfExactType.html) method but it might be better if you simply pass data into your `AdvertAppBar` class. What exactly are you trying to acheive?

Comment: did you context.widget.runtimeType

Comment: @JordanDavies From MainScreen I want to call ListScreen `(Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ListScreen()),);`
), but from `ListScreen` I want only refresh content of the `ListScreen`. Yeah, I can pass some parameter (say current form name) into AdvertAppBar constructor, but I think is there some more appropriate approach?

Comment: From what I understood from your question is that you are trying to only load the content of your `ListView` widget without reloading your `appBar` am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

[Navigator 2.0](https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade) should be able to cater this use case. I suggest using the `pages` argument in the Navigator constructor. This should help keeping a list of `Page` objects in tab and be able to update the Screen as needed. This [blog post](https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade#55f7) has a complete sample that you can try out.